# get date field based on picklist value?

Tags: visualforce, picklist, dynamic-visualforce

I need to display inputtext or inputdate based on dynamic picklist. Example i have picklist name 'section' and values a,b,c,d. By default inputtext will shown. When you select picklist value is 'd'then we need to display date instead of inputtext.

My Actual requirement is i have custom object Action. I have one picklist that displaying the some custom fields in the Action object. By default one inputtext is there. I need to display when "Due Date" field is selected in the picklist it will show Date Picker in the place of inputtext.

Page :

```
  <apex:SelectList id="selectedField" value="{!Field1}" size="1">   
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Fields}"/>
  </apex:SelectList> 

  <apex:inputText id="value1" value="{!filterValue1}"/>
```

Controller :

```
    public list<selectoption> getFields(){
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('null','--None--'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Name','Action Name'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Project__r.Name','Project'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Assigned_To__r.Name','Assign To'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Escalate_To__r.Name','Escalate To'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Business_Unit__c','Business Unit'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Meeting_Type__c','Meeting Type'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Section__c','Section'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Status__c','Status'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('RecordType.Name','Record Type'));        
            options.add(new SelectOption('Comments__c','Comments'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Due_Date__c','Due Date'));
            return options;
        }
```

Comment: wt all you have achieve till paste your code here !!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because abandoned

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample code for your requirement you need to change it according to your look!!!

NOTE : here `Rating` is a picklist and intial on page load it will show `Name` inputfield and on change of picklist from empty to `Hot` it will show you `Date` field...

here is your vf code :

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" showHeader="false" >
        <apex:form>
            <apex:pageBlock title="Account">
                <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel" title="Account Test">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
                                <apex:pageblocksectionitem
                                    rendered="{!IF(AND(account == 'Name',
                                    account.Rating == ''), True, False)}">
                                       <apex:inputText id="name"
                                            value="{!account.Name}">
                                        </apex:inputText>
                                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

                                <apex:pageblocksectionitem
                                    rendered="{!IF(AND(account == 'date__c',
                                    account.Rating == 'Hot'), True, False)}">
                                       <apex:inputdate id="date"
                                            value="{!account.date__c}">
                                        </apex:inputdate>
                                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>

                                <apex:pageblocksectionitem
                                    rendered="{!IF(account == 'Rating',True,False)}">
                                        <apex:inputField id="rating"
                                            value="{!account.Rating}">
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePanel" />
                                        </apex:inputField>
                                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                        </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:pageBlock >
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Cheerrsss Enjoy!!!